# Active record do not send created at and updated at

Tags: mysql, activerecord

We have a table with columns:
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

When we are updating it from active record the insert query contains created_at and updated_at columns.

Even after setting
config.active_record.record_timestamps = false 
Active record is sending created_at and updated_at as null.

Is there any way to not send these columns at all as we want to handle it at mysql level.

Answer (score 0):

as far as mysql concerned, your updated_on columns should be as per below for auto update-

```
updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```